# ckeditor add <iframe> tag in editor

Tags: iframe, drupal, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in a drupal 7 site. I want to put iframe tag inside the editor.
Currently what happen when we put iframe in ckeditor.

```
<iframe src="http://www.lipsum.com/"></iframe>
```

It convert that iframe tag with a img tag with some special attribute and URL.

```
<img class="cke_iframe" data-cke-realelement="%3Ciframe%20src%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lipsum.com%2F%22%20class%3D%22placeholder-tool%20helpTool-placeholder%22%20scrolling%3D%22no%22%20frameborder%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E" data-cke-real-node-type="1" alt="IFrame" title="IFrame" align="" src="http://testsite.com/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/images/spacer.gif?t=C9A85WF" data-cke-real-element-type="iframe" data-cke-resizable="true">
```

Which I do not want. I want to make the ckeditor to print exact iframe tag there not the img tag like this.

```
<iframe src="http://www.lipsum.com/"></iframe>
```

So that If I want to perform a task in iframe so I can do that inside the editor.

Thank you in advance

**Addition 2:**

I need the iframe should work in editor itself. It should not convert iframe to img on node add or edit page also.

[image]

It should like this
[image]

Not like this
[image]
[image]

Comment: I posted last addition in my answer. I hope that helps. Cheers.

Comment: I posted a comment there. I think I have to make some edit editor.js of ckeditor library file.

Comment: Trick to override that option in new releases of CKEditor is to find createFakeParserElement function for iframe and remove it.  I've posted details below so someone can use that in future. Good job Sunny.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I have to make one line change in ckeditor.js at line number 8194:

```js
return m.createFakeParserElement(p, 'cke_iframe', 'iframe', true);
```

To

```js
return p;
```

So it is not creating FakeParser for iframe. And when I put a iframe in edit mode so I see the iframe exactly not the image in place of that.
It is a little hack I used for this functionality.

Thank you Darko for help on this.

Comment: Great job. I will try that on newest release.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem solution:**

In current newest release of CKEditor (4.5.8) there is a minified file ckeditor.js. In order to have iframe enabled in edit mode you will have to change next line in that file:

```
return a.createFakeParserElement(b,"cke_iframe","iframe",!0)
```

into:

```
return (b)
```

Due to security reasons that option is by default disabled and this is the way how you can override it.
That is solution for this particular problem. Below are some of possible problem solutions if you have problems with iframe in CKEditor in drupal 7.

Addition:

Go on:

admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html (assuming you use that text format) and add `<iframe>` in Filter settings (in Allowed HTML tags).

When you post iframe in ckeditor now make sure you don't post it inside any other tag.

ex.:

```
<p some text <iframe src="http://www.lipsum.com/"></iframe> <br> </p>
```

that will not work.

```
<p>some text </p> <iframe src="http://www.lipsum.com/"></iframe>
```

that will work

Best way is to go on "source" mode in ckeditor and insert iframe there on place you want.

**Addition 2:**

From your comments i assume you trying all this on online ckeditor? You can't see final result there (node page view) because there is showed only edit view (which is temporary).

Ckeditor converts all your content based on settings (not just basic settings in texts format). For instance ckeditor converts some HTML reserved characters in they entity names or entity numbers because ckeditor itself using HTML to show you preview in edit mode.

ex:

```
<iframe src="http://www.lipsum.com/"></iframe>
```

is converted in:

```
<p>&lt;iframe src="http://www.lipsum.com/"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;</p>
```

You can see there that "<" is converted in `"&lt;"` and ">" is converted in `&gt;`. Browser need "< >" in source to properly load iframe. So solution is to using "source" option in ckeditor.[image]

So i will repeat once more. Enter text, pictures and all content you need in ckeditor edit mode. When you want to add iframe you go on source mode and put it in content (in that way ckeditor will not convert HTML reserved characters, or maybe some else in your url). 
[image]

Of course you can edit your iframe there and format size, border, scrolling etc...After saving your content you should see iframe properly loaded. In your case:
[image]

**Addition 3:**

Due to security reasons, to prevent users from breaking site layout and/or to avoid posting invalid HTML that possibility is disabled (like iframe working inside editor). If you are so determent to achieve that you can always go with old modules because in new ones that doesn't work.

In new library there is an option you can try:

```
admin/config/content/ckeditor
```

There you can edit Full profile and under ADVANCED CONTENT FILTER you can try disable Advanced content filter. Flush the cache after that. If that not working go with old modules.

1. Go disable module ckeditor
2. Install [wysiwyg](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg)
3. Install old ckeditor library (just copy old library in /sites/all/libraries )
4. You need CKEditor 3.3.1 and older
5. Go on admin/config/content/wysiwyg and select that library

When you do this you should considering all the risks. Hope this post will be helpful for someone else too. Cheers.

Comment: No, on that site content will be created by authorized user. So if I will change the format to php code so it will be breach of security for the site.
Also I must need ckeditor there. I mean, I cannot remove ckeditor. So I need a way to put iframe inside the editor.

Comment: ok, Tried this but not working for me.
Let me explain you bit more about this. I am using full html format as a default for my ckeditor. So it do not need to add iframe or any other tag there because it accept all the tags.
Also I have go to the ckeditor configuration and configure it like this config.allowedcontent = true
It allow us to use all the tag in ckeditor. And I am able to add iframe there.
But the problem is that when I try to add iframe in ckeditor let say google map iframe for example. So it create a image of current location of google and show that image in editor.

Comment: I am not talking about the node view page. I am talking about the node edit page. Where we see editor.
Example if you try http://ckeditor.com/demo#full and put a iframe there it will automatically become image tag. You can check that using inspect element.
I need to put a iframe exactly not the image in editor so that I can perform some task inside the iframe in editor window.
It is ok for me to use custom plugin of ckeditor so you can tell me if there is a way to do this using custom plugin of ckeditor I am familiar with that also.

Comment: Why you trying in online CKeditor? Try on ckeditor on your real site. That iframe in online editor is converted in image (as you saw when you inspect that page) via some js that ckeditor using. After saving the node that image will be converted in real iframe (in online editor you can't see that because you can't save content there) . Node page edit temporary and you should not look at that. Node page view is what is matter. I will add some addition in answer now...

Comment: online Ckeditor is just an example to show you the problem.
I know that when we save the content it convert the img to iframe and we will see the iframe when we visit to that content (node).
But that is not my problem. I want the iframe in edit or add page itself.
I cannot disclose my website URL till the development finish. So I just sent you example of online ckeditor. That is working exactly same as I see on add or editor page.

Comment: Hi Darko, Thank you for hard try on this question. I tried to disable the advance content filter from admin configuration. But unfortunately it does not work.
I cannot change the module currently using [ckeditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor). If I remove this module and install wysiwyg module so I have to move all my custom plugins and design to wysiwyg module. I know the ckeditor is also work with wysiwyg module but believe me it will not be good for me to use that. If you tried to disable advance content filter and got success so can you please share screenshot of that? Thank you

Comment: I think your best option is to go with older version if you are so desperate to make editor to work on that way. Good luck and put answer here if you succeed.