# iframe not showing up on drupal page

Tags: iframe, drupal, display

I am trying to display another page (external webpage) on my drupal page.  My approach is to embed the page in an iframe as follows:

```
<iframe frameborder="1" height="100" scrolling="auto" src="http://mywebpage.com/specific_page" width="80%"></iframe>
```

So far I only see the iframe box but the content is not showing up. I've switched between Full HTML, Filtered HTML and Full HTML with IMCE but none worked.  I also tried a couple different options from google search but no. Your help is sought pls.  Thanks

Comment: Which editor you using?

Comment: You can find answer for you in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36602975/ckeditor-add-iframe-tag-in-editor/36604138#36604138. Look my post there, it explains more then you need here.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest solution i think would be using PHP filter module which gives you ability to use custom code without filtration as Filtered and Full HTML filter do.

If you are only one who can add code with PHP filter(do not give this possibility to other users!) you can go straight forward with this approach.

Hope it will fit for you.